# how to calculate the probabilty to draw a X form a gaussian pdf

Tags: conditional-probability, density-function

Given a gaussian distribution, we draw a $X$ from it. What will the probability of drawing that $X$?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you add to your question by describing what you've tried so far and what you need help to understand? Is this a homework/course question? If so, please add the self-study tag.

Answer (score 1):

The probability is zero.

A probability is a length times a width.  It is an area.  If the height is the density, then the width is zero because it is exactly one point.  You can calculate a probability between two points, but not at a point.

Comment: I prefer to think of it as 'the probability (of getting any specific number in a Gaussian distribution) is infinitesimally small and therefore approximately equal to zero'. But I like your way of thinking about it too.

Comment: @Izy I think the proper answer is that it has measure zero because there are a countable number of points (1) mapping onto a continuum.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't argue with that definition, just thinking back to when I was learning, the way I described it helped me to visualise (& therefore remember) it.